# Python(pandas): removing duplicates based on two columns keeping row with flag in another column

Tags: python, pandas

new to python pandas, need to drop duplicate index rows and only keep one row among the duplicates based on the flag of one column, example as below:

```
Index value 1 value2 flag
1       10     20     on
1       30     40     off
2       11     22     on
2       32     42     off
3       12     22     on
3       33     43     off
```

and after filter based on index and flag cloumn, the output should be:

```
Index value 1 value2 flag
1       10     20     on    
2       11     22     on
3       12     22     on
```

how to do this with pandas df, should I use the drop_duplicates method?

Comment: What if there is no flag value that says "on" for a given index? Can you explain what happens in this case?

Comment: What if there are two "on" for same index. In that case, which on should be kept?

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
df=df.reset_index()
df=df.sort_values(by=['index','flag'])
df= df.drop_duplicates('index', keep='last')
```

This assumes that your flags are actually 'on' and 'off', thus if you sort your values by `index` and `flag`,  `on` will always be last. It also assumes that your index's name is `index`.

Comment: Thanks! let me try.

Answer (score 1):

try with this

```
df = df[df['flag']=='on'].drop_duplicates(subset='index', keep='last')
```

it filters only the rows with on in flag and drops then the duplicates in index

Answer (score 1):

```
df.sort_values('flag').drop_duplicates('Index', inplace = True, keep = "last")
```

This one line should solve your problem.

Comment: what if same index has two off ? your solution would keep one off

Comment: There is no information for that in the question. From sample, it looks like there is always one on and one off. There are several conditions that might come up. What if there are two on, in that case your solution will keep one on and drop the other one.